# Column information automatically given to uploaded files

Tags: document-library, managed-metadata

I'm trying to make a folder in my documents list, that when a file is uploaded to that folder, it automatically populates columns with information associated with that folder. For instance: I'd like a folder called Cardiology, and then I'd like for when you upload a file to that folder, it will generate a column that says Cancer as metadata (I think is what it's called)? Any help would be appreciated. Right now I have my entire documents library with no folders, everything is organized by manually entered data into columns. I have over like 40 filters to organize things, but I'd prefer to just do folders within the library that automatically does information when drag and dropped into it. I hope I explained it well and any help with this is appreciated.

Comment: column default values in the library settings

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to achieve is possible to implement if you use Document Sets instead of Folders, then you can leverage the Shared Columns feature so that some fields are automatically populated for files inside a Document Set.

[Here is a nice and simple blog that explains how to do that.](http://en.share-gate.com/blog/document-sets-making-your-metadata-shine)